# Unable to run Android project on BlackBerry minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1)

Tags: android, android-studio, blackberry

I am trying to adapt a project to run on BlackBerry OS 10 using Android Studio and the BlackBerry Plugin.

When I connect the device I can use ADB to connect (something like "adb connect 172.0.0.1:57248") which connects the device and it shows its name as connected.

When I go into Studio and click the BlackBerry button the device is listed and I can click play.

[image: BlackBerry in ADB Proxy]

When I click play in Studio I get a list of devices and the BlackBerry is there (I only have a Z10 for testing) but there is no name next to is and it says it is not able to run because minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1).

[image]

It seems to me that the device (or something in between) is not reporting the correct API level of the device and so the default is coming back (speculation).

EDIT
Here is it showing the error.

[image: image with error]

Also, this is Android 2.0 but it does the same in 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is to update to the new Blackberry Android Runtime. The problem occurs with the latest OS update 10.3.2.2836.

In order to install the update, you have to click on this URL from your Blackberry browser. It will redirect you to the update on Blackberry World: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/39879918

This URL will not work from a regular browser, you must access it from the device you want to update.

After you've installed the update, you must reboot your device and your device will be detected as an Android 4.3 API 18 device.

Additional instructions are available here: http://crackberry.com/if-youve-been-unable-download-android-runtime-update-try-now